# relations between controllers in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, controller

I'm writing a web-application in symfony2 for the first time.
i've just decided to split my server-side into several controllers.
i'm creating my base object in my default controller and as the user makes some choices and the data gets more specific I want to handle it (each data-class) in a different controller. for that to happen in need to tie the new subclass to it's base class. something like

```
// default controller
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public $trip;

    public function startAction()
    {
        // get data from request etc.
        // ...
        $trip = new Trip();
    }

    // handling everything else
 }
```

and then,

```
// stage controller
class StageController extends Controller
{
    public $stage;

    public function setStageAction()
    {
        // get data from request etc.
        // ...
        $stage = new Stage();
        $stage->SetTrip($trip); // doesn't work of course.
    }

    // handling everything else
 }
```

trying to figure out how to handle the situation above i've been wondering what's the relations of the controllers within a bundle is like. 
couldn't find nothing but "set the controller as a service" which may be a solution to my situation but doesn't help me understand the architecture.
i guess maybe it's a dumb question, 
still,
anyone?

Comment: Does the section `// get data from request etc` get your newly created trip from databse? Please provide some more information. You will need to persist your trip between the requests somehow - how do you plan to do that? save it in session, database? i have problems understanding your goal. There usually (if not using ESI or `->forward()`) only **one** controller invoked when serving a response.

Comment: thanks nifr. your comment made things much clearer to me. I now save everything in the session and only in the end I save it to the DB, so no real need in communication between controllers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In symfony you can use services for this.

Every service will do the job, what you delegate to it.
For exmaple, there is a service called StageManager, then you create there a function create Stage, wher you do all your entity creation and mapping and then you can persist it to the database.

Here you can see an example what is a service, how can you create one and how to use it in a controller.

[Link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)